# Adding Extra params on google callback

Tags: python, django

I am using djang-allauth for google social auth. how can i add extra request params on google inbuild callback url.

i am trying to add params into provider_login_url but i am not getting that params on callback.

{% provider_login_url 'google' action='reauthenticate' method='oauth2' user_type='admin' %}